# Re-hide remote branch from git-branch

Tags: git, branch

I clone a remote repo with `git clone`. The repo has many branches.  In my local terminal, I type `git branch` which shows `master`.  If I type `git branch -a`, I see all branches both local and remote. If I switch to a remote branch with `git checkout remote-branch`, and proceed to type `git branch`, I will see both `master` and `remote-branch`. I do my work on `remote-branch`, some code features don't work out, I decide to go back to master with `git checkout master` and I don't want to delete this `remote-branch`.

Suppose I want to re-hide `remote-branch` from `git branch`, as it was in the beginning when I cloned the repo, after going back to `master`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `git checkout remote-branch`, git first tries to find that ref in local ones.

Since you only have `master` (and provided you're running a recent enough git version), it then checks if there's a remote branch with that name. If so, it creates a local branch with the same name, and sets upstream to the remote one.

That's why you can see it listed when you do `git branch`

To "hide" it, you'll have to delete it. *(Keep in mind that the remote branch isn't in any way impacted by this.)*

```
git checkout master
git branch -d <branchName>

# the above will fail with a message if the branch is unmerged
# (has commits which aren't merged into `master`)
# if you do want the deletion to occur nonetheless, insist with
git branch -D <branchName>
```